# what is purpose of condition used for if() statement? C++

Tags: c++

How can I send a NULL pointer from the caller, as any of the three parameters, to the CalcArea function, in the following program? No matter how I modify the condition (not content), of the if () statement, I still see the output from cout << "why am I seeing this..." <

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 void CalcArea(const double* const pPi,
               const double* const pRadius,
               double* const pArea)
 {
     if (pPi && pRadius && pArea)
     *pArea = (*pPi) * (*pRadius) * (*pRadius);
     cout<< "why am I seeing this?..." <<endl;
 }

 int main()
 {
     const double Pi = 3.1416;

     cout<< "enter radius of circle: ";
     double Radius = 0;
     cin>> Radius;

     double Area = 0;
     CalcArea (&Pi, &Radius, &Area);

     cout<< "area is = " <<Area<<endl;

     cout<< "press enter to continue..." <<endl;
     cin.ignore(10, '\n');
     cin.get();

     return 0;
 }
```

Please help me to understand. It says in my book that "you don't want the function to calculate the area if the caller inadvertently sends a NULL pointer as any of the three parameters", but under what conditions exactly could this occure? What is the condition of the if() statement meant to prevent. Remember I am only beginning. Thank you all, sincerely, newmanadam

Comment: I messed up when indenting now program will not run. Should have checked first. Will do right away. Very sorry

Comment: Side note:  this is actually a silly thing to check, and a waste of typing.

Answer (score 3):

Only the line immediately following the *if* depends on the evaluation.

```
if (condition)
    statement
```

If you want both lines to only run if the condition holds, use curly braces.

```
if (condition)
{
    multiple
    statements
}
```

The if condition here simply checks that none of the references you give it are null. This can happen if you explicitly call your function with NULL

```
CalcArea(&Pi, NULL, &Area);
```

Or if you are using a pointer, which has previously been set to null. Since you are learning from a book, I would assume it will explain them to you soon enough.

Answer (score 1):

`if()` works for one statement, in your case for one line:

```
 if (pPi && pRadius && pArea)
     *pArea = (*pPi) * (*pRadius) * (*pRadius);
 cout << "why am I seeing this?..." <<endl; // cout is outside of if()
```

you need create block of code to make `cout` output conditional:

```
 if (pPi && pRadius && pArea) {
     *pArea = (*pPi) * (*pRadius) * (*pRadius);
     cout << "why am I seeing this?..." <<endl;
 }
```

Condition itself is used to check that none of three pointers are equal to `nullptr`, as dereferencing such pointer would lead to undefined behavior, in simple words to prevent program to crush on invalid input for this function.

Answer (score 0):

You want to brace the whole block which refers to the condition:

```
void CalcArea(const double* const pPi, 
 const double* const pRadius, 
 double* const pArea)
 {
    if (pPi && pRadius && pArea)
    {
         *pArea = (*pPi) * (*pRadius) * (*pRadius);
         cout << "why am I seeing this?..." <<endl;
         cout << "Because all pointers are != NULL" <<endl;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you all very much, I appreciate it. And again I am sorry for having had to edit my post to correct the initially broken program caused by my indentation. From now on I will check to see if my posted program compiles. Also, see my small contribution to upgrading code blocks to c++14.